# Do ARKit anchors persist after pause and run again?

Tags: ios, arkit

I am considering developing an ARKit app, but before deciding to buy an iPhone I would like to ask two questions that are crucial for me. Please let me know if this has already been asked, as I could not find it somewhere else online.

The questions:
1. Let's say the motion tracking gets lost (e.g., when pointing to a white wall) and then recovers again. Does it localize in the same frame of reference or it starts from scratch? Also, are the anchors preserved?
2. Let's say I pause the session and then run it again (e.g., by leaving the app and then coming back). Does is localize back to the frame of reference from before the pause? Also, are the anchors preserved?

I am asking this because I know that localization does not work in ARCore yet and I was wondering about its state in ARKit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARKit has two or three ways to lose tracking (depending on how you think of them); each has a different effect on anchors.

#### 1. TemporARy tracking quality issues

(I honestly fumbled caps lock in the middle of that word. My keyboard is making the puns for me!)

In the first situation you mention, and similar cases — pointing at a blank wall, giving the phone a sudden jostle, moving from a darkened area into bright light or vice versa — your app will get notified of changes to ARKit’s [tracking state](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera.trackingstate) that effect the quality of camera pose tracking.

When the tracking state is `limited`, ARKit’s idea of where the world is might be out of sync with the real world, but it still has enough information to be able to relocalize when the situation passes. That includes anchors. (Try for yourself; run one of Apple’s ARKit sample code projects, and cover the camera lens for a bit while moving the phone.)

If whatever situation is affecting the tracking state persists for a long time, relocalization is unlikely to succeed. It can help to track how long you’ve been in limited tracking and offer the user a way to restart the session if things get too out of whack.

#### 2 and 3.  Session interruption and resume or restart

If something happens that interrupts ARKit’s ability to receive camera and motion data — like the incoming phone call screen on iPhone, or the user responding to an interactive notification, your app gets a [`sessionWasInterrupted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2891620-sessionwasinterrupted) message. There’s nothing you can do in this case (as far as session management is concerned) other than wait for a corresponding [`sessionInterruptionEnded`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsessionobserver/2891619-sessioninterruptionended) message.

If the interruption was brief and the device hasn’t moved much since, there’s a chance of automatic relocalization. Of course, you can’t tell how much the device has been moved because motion tracking was off... you can make an educated guess based on the duration of interruption and how sensitive your AR experience is to tracking precision, and decide accordingly whether to restart the session. (For example, a game that has space invaders floating in the air is less affected than an app that lets the user trace out a floor plan by marking walls.)

> Aside: Traditional iOS UI patterns like modal view controllers, tab views, and navigation controllers can push the view hosting an AR session away, interrupting the session and losing tracking. Like Apple’s [Human Interface Guidelines for AR](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/technologies/augmented-reality/) suggest, it can be good to use things like popover views instead, so that you keep the AR experience onscreen and the session running.

When/if you do [restart your AR session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession/2875735-run), you have a choice of whether to keep anchors or reset tracking. If you’ve already lost localization, what this really means is whether you keep track of anchors in arbitrary coordinate space they’re defined in (even though that space doesn’t line up with the real world anymore), or just lose all the anchors.

Short of restarting the session, though, there’s nothing that’ll cause anchors to be removed. And if you lose tracking temporarily enough to get relocalization, anchors that track real-world objects (that is, plane anchors, as opposed to the ones you manually create) should adjust back to realistic positions even if the coordinate systems doesn’t quite line up the way it used to.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @rickster, for the thorough answer! Now I understand clearly how it works.